# using await in async function vs. not using await javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

If I have something like this:

```
(async () => {
    let i = 100000;
    while(i--);
})();
```

compared to something like this:

```
(async () => {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let i = 100000;
        while(i--);
        return resolve();
    });
    await promise;
})();
```

**Are these two exactly the same thing?**

**EDIT**

By same thing, I mean something along the lines of:

1. Same execution time?
2. If I were to console.log something, same results?
3. Is code in the async function for both synchronous or asynchronous, if, say, I add more code after the `while` on the first block, and after the `await` in the second block?

Comment: First thing I notice: the first snippet yields an immediately fulfilled promise, whereas the second one doesn’t get immediately fulfilled.

Comment: Exactly the same in what sense?  In their behavior in the context of surrounding/calling code?  In how they transpile?

Comment: An `async` function always returns a promise.

Comment: Oddly, in firefox, the while loop seems to run 10 times faster in the second version

Comment: The second code is redundant, an async function wraps everything in a promise anyway, why mess it up?

Comment: If you are not going to use the `await` keyword in a function what's the point of declaring it `async`..?